# Shared memory tree

Tags: c, unix, ipc

I have two processes. The parent scans the system and writes some info into the binary tree. At the same time, the child waits for connections on a TCP port.  After `accept()`, the child needs to take or delete some info from the tree.

How can I share the tree?

Comment: You better not share the tree, but provide some kind of call interface between the child and the parent to work with the tree. This can be based on any IPC mechanism (signals, pipes and such)

Comment: Currently, project uses solution based on pipes, but for some unknown reasons, i was asked to rewrite it

Comment: Well, the reasons should be clarified in order not to rewrite again.

Comment: At a minimum you'd need to use a cross-process semaphore or mutex to synchronize access to the shared data structure, so that process A won't try to modify the data structure concurrently with process B reading or writing it.  You'd also need to set up a heap that lives in the shared memory region, since a process's default allocator provides private, not shared-memory buffers.  It's unlikely to be worth the effort to make the tree a shared data structure.